# What does this while loop mean in Eloquent Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and programming in general and I'm confused with this while loop. What does the while condition of true mean? It's very confusing to me because I'm used to seeing while loops with a defined variable and a condition actually comparing something. However, in this example in the book the variable "answer" is undefined and the condition of the while loop is just "(true)".

```
    var answer;
    while (true) {
      answer = prompt("You! What is the value of 2 + 2?", "");
      if (answer == "4") {
        alert("You must be a genius or something.");
        break;
      }
      else if (answer == "3" || answer == "5") {
        alert("Almost!");
      }
      else {
        alert("You're an embarrassment.");
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this code does is it loops forever until the right number is put in.

So, `while(true){}` just runs the code until `break;` is called.

Then, `prompt(...)` waits until the user inputs a value.

If the number is correct, it alerts the user: `alert("You must be a genius or something.");`, otherwise it says `"Almost"` or `"Your an embarrassment."` and starts the loop over from step 1.

This kind of loop is really useful when you want to just keep asking until you get the result you want, as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` means **run the following forever**. But you intentionally keep `break` statements, for the code to come out from an infinite loop.

here, the answer variable gets a value from your input. The `prompt("You! What is the value of 2 + 2?", "");` asks you to input your answer and assigns your inputted value to `answer`. this loop runs as long as you enter incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, at first

```
var answer;
```

answer value is undefined.

```
answer = prompt("You! What is the value of 2 + 2?", "");
```

Above line ask user to enter some value and that value is going to store in answer variable.

```
if (answer == "4")
```

We are comparing the value, if it is "4" then loop will break using

```
break;
```

keyword.

Otherwise, the loop will still continue and ask the user.